# ASP.NET Core and JWT token lifetime

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt, token

I utilize `ASP.NET Core 2.1.1`

It is interesting that the expiration time is only being taken into account when one provides **both** `ClockSkew` - *in Startup.cs* **and** `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.TokenLifetimeInMinutes` - *in a controller*.

For instance:

```
services
  .AddJwtBearer(x =>
  {
      ...
      x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
      {
         ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(90),
         ...
```

plus

```
...
public async Task<AuthenticateOutput> Authenticate([FromBody] AuthenticateInput input)
{
   var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
   tokenHandler.TokenLifetimeInMinutes = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(90).TotalMinutes;
   ...
```

If I remove `tokenHandler.TokenLifetimeInMinutes = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(90).TotalMinutes;`
 part - the default expiration time is used.

It seems to me that `tokenHandler.TokenLifetimeInMinutes` is **still** redundant and I just misunderstand the concept of how to set the expiration time correctly.

I also tried adding expiration claim - `new Claim(ClaimTypes.Expiration, ...)` - but that didn't have much effect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51334572/jwt-token-expiration-time-asp-net-core/51334821

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`ClockSkew` property isn't about expiration itself, it compensates for [clock skew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_skew).

To setup token expiration you have to specify it on token creation:

```
new JwtSecurityToken(
                ...
                expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(90),
                ....);
```

and the following code will give you string with token:

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken() { /* setup your token setting here*/ }
var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, well played! Tested it several times trying different intervals - works.

Comment: How to avoid expiration?
I have tried deleting expiry property but still it expires around 1 hour

Comment: `((JwtSecurityTokenHandler)tokenHandler).SetDefaultTimesOnTokenCreation = false;` to have it never expire.

Answer (score 0):

```
//reading the key from config
//reading the issuer from config
            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Jwt:Key"]));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(configuration["Jwt:Issuer"], configuration["Jwt:Issuer"], 
                            null, expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),
                            signingCredentials: credentials); //60mins expiration 

            string newToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
```