# middleware architechture asp.net token authentication check token if expired

Tags: c#, jwt, backend

ASP.net has many approach how to implement
token authentication without need of user.

For me I want a direct approach to do this 
as my first time to implement this
still searching for the right middleware
approach as of now but hoping everyone can help.

I am needed to add a 24 hr session 
to my application which require check 
token every request if token is expired 
should return 401

as my first time to implement in asp.net core 2.1
I want to ask your help if how I could implement 
that in the back end

when user is created the token is given and 
every request my middleware should check how many time
left before the token expire

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51334572/jwt-token-expiration-time-asp-net-core

Comment: Thanks Neil for this link , also I am thinking to use delegateHandler for the token check as well

Comment: If you need to do something nonstandard then yes, but don't try to duplicate something that is already automatic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jwt token expiration time (asp.net core)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51334572/jwt-token-expiration-time-asp-net-core)

Comment: in asp.net core i am planning delegatinghandler more simplier approach than others which is authenticationhandler which is for me i find it difficult to implement. I will paste my code here to show my progress. I need someone who implemented this already.

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank : thank you for the link but i saw this already and had a hard time how to formulate my question into code as well.